# Naive Understanding of Constructibility.

Tags: geometric-construction

I am a 10th grader and recently I came to know about "Straightedge and Compass Construction". Seriously, I was  stunned!!, we can actually predict that what can be constructed and what not by using "Straightedge and Compass" without actually drawing them. But when I tried to understand the concepts, everything just went up to my mind. I am not aware of the words "Field, Subfield,Extension,Tower..etc.." Is there any **theorem** which I can assume for a while( until I attend abstract or linear algebra class) and which is not beyond my scope(average 10th grader)  to handle any kind of Impossibility proofs.

**My knowledge**: I know much about polynomials, number theory....and everything that you can expect from an average 10th grader.

Comment: The simplest book treatment I know of is [**Famous Problems of Geometry and How to Solve Them**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486242978) by Benjamin Bold. But even this will require knowing equations for circles, algebraic manipulation skill more than you might presently have, complex numbers and trigonometry (including De Moivre's theorem). See also Chapter III: *Geometrical Constructions. The Algebra of Number Fields* (pp. 117-164) in [**What Is Mathematics?**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0195105192) by Richard Courant and Herbert Robbins.

Comment: Also: Chapter 17: *Construction by Straightedge and Compass* (pp. 413-439) in [**Mathematics. The Man-Made Universe**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486404501) by Sherman K. Stein (probably the most elementary reference I've given, but much of the material is in the exercises at the end of the chapter) *AND* [*Why it is impossible to trisect an angle or to construct a regular polygon of* $7$ *or* $9$ *sides by ruler and compasses*](https://archive.org/details/jstor-27950336/mode/2up) by Leonard E. Dickson.

Comment: Thanks!! It helped.

Comment: Courant & Robbins' [What is Mathematics](https://archive.org/details/whatismathematic00cour) can be borrowed from the Internet Digital Archive for an hour at a time. I've linked one copy, but [the archive](https://archive.org/) contains many different printings of the first edition. I won a copy for General Proficiency in Grade 11, and found the bulk of it approachable at that time even if I couldn't yet follow all the finer details.